# Only find() query works well for me !!!? MongoDB php

Tags: php, mongodb, jelastic

I'm working on `Jelastic` cloud platform and I'm trying to use `MongoDB` for my php website.
The only query that worked correctly for me was the `$db.collection.find();` ..

I tried executing my code exactly after the connection as following, but it also didn't work !!

```
<?php
$host = "mongodb-env-4080143.whelastic.net";
$username = "admin";
$password = "*****";

try{

$conn = new Mongo($host, array("username" => $username, "password" => $password));



    $db = $conn->selectDB('e-shoppingoMongo');


   if ($conn){

    echo " it is working ";
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'users');

$db->users->insert({ 
    fname : "kkkk", lname: "Ash", password: "x" ,
    email: "x@x.com",phoneNo: 000 ,company: "x",
    country: "b",city:"x",street:"x"});

   }
    }catch( Exception $e){

   echo  "<center><h1>Doesn't work</h1></center>";

   exit;
}

?>
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong ?!?!? 
I really appreciate any help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked with me:

```
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'users');

    $query = array( 'fname' => $fname, 'lname' => $lname, 'password' => $passwrod,
                    'email'=>$email,'phoneNo'=> $phoneNo,'company'=>$company,
                    'country'=>$country,'city'=>$city,'street'=>$street);
$cursor = $collection->insert($query);
```